# GCM Can't read topics messages in Android client

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've two Android apps that I need for them to communicate over the Internet. So I choose the Google GCM.

I want an application to create a topic so the other app can post messages to that topic. My objective is for the two apps to exchange text data between them.

How can I make them to communicate directly? What do I put in the "to" field of the JsonObject? Or should I use the "registration_id" field and put the token ID?

Or do I need a Web Server?

I post the code for you to see what I've.

```
 if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean(context.getString(R.string.Google_Services), false)) {
        //Upstream msg
        new AsyncTask() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Object[] params) {
                try {
// Prepare JSON containing the GCM message content. What to send and where to send.
                    JSONObject jGcmData = new JSONObject();
                    JSONObject jData = new JSONObject();
                    jData.put("message", msgSend);
                    // Where to send GCM message
                    jGcmData.put("to", "/topics/phone");
                    //jGcmData.put("to","cPnatWR_2yo:APA91bFshaomZuuxEggU2rn1s_YSDoyH4zUOeOImfFXsm62dwUj2kMjbxLCWvgwKEedQlk59TxnpQoTqUjgMiDcsUJil3kZ702lk-NHSIraYM9nQ_mkf3g98gWjmusq0wNpk5o4gos8_");
                    //jGcmData.put("registration_ids","cPnatWR_2yo:APA91bFshaomZuuxEggU2rn1s_YSDoyH4zUOeOImfFXsm62dwUj2kMjbxLCWvgwKEedQlk59TxnpQoTqUjgMiDcsUJil3kZ702lk-NHSIraYM9nQ_mkf3g98gWjmusq0wNpk5o4gos8_");
                    // What to send in GCM message.
                    jGcmData.put("data", jData);

                    // Create connection to send GCM Message request.
                    URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);


                    // Send GCM message content.
                    OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
                    outputStream.write(jGcmData.toString().getBytes());

                    // Read GCM response.
                    InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                    String resp = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
                    System.out.println(resp);
                    System.out.println("Check your device/emulator for notification or logcat for " +
                            "confirmation of the receipt of the GCM message.");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to send GCM message.");
                    System.out.println("Please ensure that API_KEY has been replaced by the server " +
                            "API key, and that the device's registration token is correct (if specified).");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
```

Then the other application registered to this topic.

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
private static final String[] TOPICS = {"phone"};

public RegistrationIntentService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    try {
        // [START register_for_gcm]
        // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
        // are local.
        // R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId (the Sender ID) is typically derived from google-services.json.
        // See https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start for details on this file.
        // [START get_token]
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        instanceID.deleteInstanceID();
        String newIID = InstanceID.getInstance(this).getId();
        String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
        // [END get_token]
        Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(token);

        // Subscribe to topic channels
        subscribeTopics(token);

        // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
        // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
        // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(getString(R.string.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER), true).apply();
        // [END register_for_gcm]
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
        // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
        // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(getString(R.string.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER), false).apply();
    }
    // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
    Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(getString(R.string.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
}

/**
 * Persist registration to third-party servers.
 *
 * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
 * maintained by your application.
 *
 * @param token The new token.
 */
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // Add custom implementation, as needed.
}

/**
 * Subscribe to any GCM topics of interest, as defined by the TOPICS constant.
 *
 * @param token GCM token
 * @throws IOException if unable to reach the GCM PubSub service
 */
// [START subscribe_topics]
private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
    GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
    for (String topic : TOPICS) {
        //pubSub.unsubscribe(token,"/topics/" + topic);
        pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
    }
}
// [END subscribe_topics]
```

I include the GCM part of manifest file of the receiving app:

```
 <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="org.suportec.lost" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->
    <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="org.suportec.lost.GoogleCMListener"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
    <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="org.suportec.lost.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="org.suportec.lost.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I can't put it to work. Please help me!
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried reading this docs: (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem!

It was a problem in the GCM uses permission. They're configured with other app package. It's stupid cause works in Kitkat, but in 4 and previous, doesn't work.